Cannot map JSON to List in Dart in Flutter project (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.)
I am working with a Flutter project where I am trying to learn simple http method to work with API where I can make a call and represent the data in a listview. The problem I am facing has to do with parsing where I have been able to make the call the map data and convert it to a simple list but when I try map json list to character list I get this error

NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.

Here is the code:
Future<List<Character>> getCharacterData() async {
    List<Character> data = [];

    final uri = Uri.parse(baseUri+characters);

    try {
      final response = await http.get(
          uri,
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: access_token,
          }
      );
      print('uri: $uri');
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);

      if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {
        final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        print('jsonResponse: $jsonResponse');
        final characterList = jsonResponse['characters'] as List;

        print('CharacterList: $characterList');
        print('just checking data');

        // Map json list to character list
        data = characterList.map((json) => Character.fromJson(json)).toList();

        print('data: $data');
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print('error: $e');
      return data;
    }

    print('Here\'s the data: $data');
    return data;
}

Problem is here:
// Map json list to character list
data = characterList.map((json) => Character.fromJson(json)).toList();

Full response was:
I/flutter (23217): uri: https://dattebayo-api.onrender.com/characters
I/flutter (23217): 200
I/flutter (23217): {"characters":[{"id":1344,"name":"Naruto Uzumaki","images":["https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/d/d6/Naruto_Part_I.png","https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/7/7d/Naruto_Part_II.png"],"debut":{"manga":"Naruto Chapter #1","anime":"Naruto Episode #1","novel":"Naruto: Innocent Heart, Demonic Blood","movie":"Naruto the Movie: Ninja Clash in the Land of Snow","game":"Naruto: Konoha Ninpōchō","ova":"Find the Four-Leaf Red Clover!","appearsIn":"Anime, Manga, Novel, Game, Movie"},"family":{"father":"Minato Namikaze","mother":"Kushina Uzumaki","son":"Boruto Uzumaki","daughter":"Himawari Uzumaki","wife":"Hinata Uzumaki","adoptive son":"Kawaki","godfather":"Jiraiya"},"jutsu":["All Directions Shuriken","Baryon Mode","Big Ball Rasengan","Big Ball Rasenshuriken","Big Ball Spiralling Serial Zone Spheres","Boil Release: Unrivalled Strength","Chakra Transfer Technique","Clone Body Blow","Clone Flying Arrow","Clone Spinning Heel Drop (Anime only)","Combination Transformation","Continuous Tailed Beast
I/flutter (23217): jsonResponse: {characters: [{id: 1344, name: Naruto Uzumaki, images: [https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/d/d6/Naruto_Part_I.png, https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/7/7d/Naruto_Part_II.png], debut: {manga: Naruto Chapter #1, anime: Naruto Episode #1, novel: Naruto: Innocent Heart, Demonic Blood, movie: Naruto the Movie: Ninja Clash in the Land of Snow, game: Naruto: Konoha Ninpōchō, ova: Find the Four-Leaf Red Clover!, appearsIn: Anime, Manga, Novel, Game, Movie}, family: {father: Minato Namikaze, mother: Kushina Uzumaki, son: Boruto Uzumaki, daughter: Himawari Uzumaki, wife: Hinata Uzumaki, adoptive son: Kawaki, godfather: Jiraiya}, jutsu: [All Directions Shuriken, Baryon Mode, Big Ball Rasengan, Big Ball Rasenshuriken, Big Ball Spiralling Serial Zone Spheres, Boil Release: Unrivalled Strength, Chakra Transfer Technique, Clone Body Blow, Clone Flying Arrow, Clone Spinning Heel Drop (Anime only), Combination Transformation, Continuous Tailed Beast Balls, Crescent Moon Rasengan, Ear
I/flutter (23217): CharacterList: [{id: 1344, name: Naruto Uzumaki, images: [https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/d/d6/Naruto_Part_I.png, https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/7/7d/Naruto_Part_II.png], debut: {manga: Naruto Chapter #1, anime: Naruto Episode #1, novel: Naruto: Innocent Heart, Demonic Blood, movie: Naruto the Movie: Ninja Clash in the Land of Snow, game: Naruto: Konoha Ninpōchō, ova: Find the Four-Leaf Red Clover!, appearsIn: Anime, Manga, Novel, Game, Movie}, family: {father: Minato Namikaze, mother: Kushina Uzumaki, son: Boruto Uzumaki, daughter: Himawari Uzumaki, wife: Hinata Uzumaki, adoptive son: Kawaki, godfather: Jiraiya}, jutsu: [All Directions Shuriken, Baryon Mode, Big Ball Rasengan, Big Ball Rasenshuriken, Big Ball Spiralling Serial Zone Spheres, Boil Release: Unrivalled Strength, Chakra Transfer Technique, Clone Body Blow, Clone Flying Arrow, Clone Spinning Heel Drop (Anime only), Combination Transformation, Continuous Tailed Beast Balls, Crescent Moon Rasengan, Earth Release: 
I/flutter (23217): just checking data
I/flutter (23217): error: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
I/flutter (23217): Receiver: null
I/flutter (23217): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => CharacterElement)

This is my model class:
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final character = characterFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Character characterFromJson(String str) => Character.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String characterToJson(Character data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Character {
  List<CharacterElement> characters;
  int currentPage;
  int pageSize;
  int total;

  Character({
    required this.characters,
    required this.currentPage,
    required this.pageSize,
    required this.total,
  });

  factory Character.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Character(
    characters: List<CharacterElement>.from(json["characters"].map((x) => CharacterElement.fromJson(x))),
    currentPage: json["currentPage"],
    pageSize: json["pageSize"],
    total: json["total"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "characters": List<dynamic>.from(characters.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "currentPage": currentPage,
    "pageSize": pageSize,
    "total": total,
  };
}

class CharacterElement {
  int id;
  String name;
  List<String> images;
  Debut debut;
  Family? family;
  List<String> jutsu;
  List<String>? natureType;
  Personal personal;
  Rank? rank;
  List<String>? tools;
  VoiceActors voiceActors;
  List<String>? uniqueTraits;

  CharacterElement({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.images,
    required this.debut,
    this.family,
    required this.jutsu,
    this.natureType,
    required this.personal,
    this.rank,
    this.tools,
    required this.voiceActors,
    this.uniqueTraits,
  });

  factory CharacterElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CharacterElement(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    images: List<String>.from(json["images"].map((x) => x)),
    debut: Debut.fromJson(json["debut"]),
    family: json["family"] == null ? null : Family.fromJson(json["family"]),
    jutsu: List<String>.from(json["jutsu"].map((x) => x)),
    natureType: json["natureType"] == null ? [] : List<String>.from(json["natureType"]!.map((x) => x)),
    personal: Personal.fromJson(json["personal"]),
    rank: json["rank"] == null ? null : Rank.fromJson(json["rank"]),
    tools: json["tools"] == null ? [] : List<String>.from(json["tools"]!.map((x) => x)),
    voiceActors: VoiceActors.fromJson(json["voiceActors"]),
    uniqueTraits: json["uniqueTraits"] == null ? [] : List<String>.from(json["uniqueTraits"]!.map((x) => x)),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "images": List<dynamic>.from(images.map((x) => x)),
    "debut": debut.toJson(),
    "family": family?.toJson(),
    "jutsu": List<dynamic>.from(jutsu.map((x) => x)),
    "natureType": natureType == null ? [] : List<dynamic>.from(natureType!.map((x) => x)),
    "personal": personal.toJson(),
    "rank": rank?.toJson(),
    "tools": tools == null ? [] : List<dynamic>.from(tools!.map((x) => x)),
    "voiceActors": voiceActors.toJson(),
    "uniqueTraits": uniqueTraits == null ? [] : List<dynamic>.from(uniqueTraits!.map((x) => x)),
  };
}

class Debut {
  String manga;
  String anime;
  String? novel;
  String? movie;
  String game;
  String? ova;
  AppearsIn appearsIn;

  Debut({
    required this.manga,
    required this.anime,
    this.novel,
    this.movie,
    required this.game,
    this.ova,
    required this.appearsIn,
  });

  factory Debut.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Debut(
    manga: json["manga"],
    anime: json["anime"],
    novel: json["novel"],
    movie: json["movie"],
    game: json["game"],
    ova: json["ova"],
    appearsIn: appearsInValues.map[json["appearsIn"]]!,
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "manga": manga,
    "anime": anime,
    "novel": novel,
    "movie": movie,
    "game": game,
    "ova": ova,
    "appearsIn": appearsInValues.reverse[appearsIn],
  };
}

enum AppearsIn {
  ANIME_MANGA_GAME,
  ANIME_MANGA_GAME_MOVIE,
  ANIME_MANGA_NOVEL_GAME_MOVIE
}

final appearsInValues = EnumValues({
  "Anime, Manga, Game": AppearsIn.ANIME_MANGA_GAME,
  "Anime, Manga, Game, Movie": AppearsIn.ANIME_MANGA_GAME_MOVIE,
  "Anime, Manga, Novel, Game, Movie": AppearsIn.ANIME_MANGA_NOVEL_GAME_MOVIE
});

class Family {
  String? father;
  String? mother;
  String? son;
  String? daughter;
  String? wife;
  String? adoptiveSon;
  String? godfather;
  String? brother;
  String? cloneSon;
  String? familyGrandmother;
  String? sister;
  String? nephew;
  String? uncle;
  String? adoptiveMother;
  String? adoptiveSons;
  String? adoptiveBrother;
  String? clone;
  String? godson;
  String? greatGrandfather;
  String? grandfather;
  String? grandmother;
  String? cousin;
  String? geneticTemplateParent;
  String? cloneBrother;
  String? pet;
  String? grandson;
  String? granddaughter;
  String? granduncle;
  String? aunt;
  String? firstCousinOnceRemoved;
  String? host;
  String? niece;
  String? lover;
  String? creator;
  String? geneticTemplate;

  Family({
    this.father,
    this.mother,
    this.son,
    this.daughter,
    this.wife,
    this.adoptiveSon,
    this.godfather,
    this.brother,
    this.cloneSon,
    this.familyGrandmother,
    this.sister,
    this.nephew,
    this.uncle,
    this.adoptiveMother,
    this.adoptiveSons,
    this.adoptiveBrother,
    this.clone,
    this.godson,
    this.greatGrandfather,
    this.grandfather,
    this.grandmother,
    this.cousin,
    this.geneticTemplateParent,
    this.cloneBrother,
    this.pet,
    this.grandson,
    this.granddaughter,
    this.granduncle,
    this.aunt,
    this.firstCousinOnceRemoved,
    this.host,
    this.niece,
    this.lover,
    this.creator,
    this.geneticTemplate,
  });

  factory Family.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Family(
    father: json["father"],
    mother: json["mother"],
    son: json["son"],
    daughter: json["daughter"],
    wife: json["wife"],
    adoptiveSon: json["adoptive son"],
    godfather: json["godfather"],
    brother: json["brother"],
    cloneSon: json["clone/son"],
    familyGrandmother: json["grandmother "],
    sister: json["sister"],
    nephew: json["nephew"],
    uncle: json["uncle"],
    adoptiveMother: json["adoptive mother"],
    adoptiveSons: json["adoptive sons"],
    adoptiveBrother: json["adoptive brother"],
    clone: json["clone"],
    godson: json["godson"],
    greatGrandfather: json["great-grandfather"],
    grandfather: json["grandfather"],
    grandmother: json["grandmother"],
    cousin: json["cousin"],
    geneticTemplateParent: json["genetic template/parent"],
    cloneBrother: json["clone/brother"],
    pet: json["pet "],
    grandson: json["grandson"],
    granddaughter: json["granddaughter"],
    granduncle: json["granduncle"],
    aunt: json["aunt"],
    firstCousinOnceRemoved: json["first cousin once removed"],
    host: json["host"],
    niece: json["niece"],
    lover: json["lover"],
    creator: json["creator"],
    geneticTemplate: json["genetic template"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "father": father,
    "mother": mother,
    "son": son,
    "daughter": daughter,
    "wife": wife,
    "adoptive son": adoptiveSon,
    "godfather": godfather,
    "brother": brother,
    "clone/son": cloneSon,
    "grandmother ": familyGrandmother,
    "sister": sister,
    "nephew": nephew,
    "uncle": uncle,
    "adoptive mother": adoptiveMother,
    "adoptive sons": adoptiveSons,
    "adoptive brother": adoptiveBrother,
    "clone": clone,
    "godson": godson,
    "great-grandfather": greatGrandfather,
    "grandfather": grandfather,
    "grandmother": grandmother,
    "cousin": cousin,
    "genetic template/parent": geneticTemplateParent,
    "clone/brother": cloneBrother,
    "pet ": pet,
    "grandson": grandson,
    "granddaughter": granddaughter,
    "granduncle": granduncle,
    "aunt": aunt,
    "first cousin once removed": firstCousinOnceRemoved,
    "host": host,
    "niece": niece,
    "lover": lover,
    "creator": creator,
    "genetic template": geneticTemplate,
  };
}

class Personal {
  String? birthdate;
  Sex sex;
  Age? age;
  Height? height;
  Weight? weight;
  BloodType? bloodType;
  dynamic kekkeiGenkai;
  dynamic classification;
  String? tailedBeast;
  dynamic occupation;
  List<String> affiliation;
  dynamic team;
  dynamic clan;
  List<String>? titles;
  String? status;
  String? kekkeiMra;
  dynamic partner;
  String? species;

  Personal({
    this.birthdate,
    required this.sex,
    this.age,
    this.height,
    this.weight,
    this.bloodType,
    this.kekkeiGenkai,
    this.classification,
    this.tailedBeast,
    this.occupation,
    required this.affiliation,
    this.team,
    this.clan,
    this.titles,
    this.status,
    this.kekkeiMra,
    this.partner,
    this.species,
  });

  factory Personal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Personal(
    birthdate: json["birthdate"],
    sex: sexValues.map[json["sex"]]!,
    age: json["age"] == null ? null : Age.fromJson(json["age"]),
    height: json["height"] == null ? null : Height.fromJson(json["height"]),
    weight: json["weight"] == null ? null : Weight.fromJson(json["weight"]),
    bloodType: bloodTypeValues.map[json["bloodType"]]!,
    kekkeiGenkai: json["kekkeiGenkai"],
    classification: json["classification"],
    tailedBeast: json["tailedBeast"],
    occupation: json["occupation"],
    affiliation: List<String>.from(json["affiliation"].map((x) => x)),
    team: json["team"],
    clan: json["clan"],
    titles: json["titles"] == null ? [] : List<String>.from(json["titles"]!.map((x) => x)),
    status: json["status"],
    kekkeiMra: json["kekkeiMōra"],
    partner: json["partner"],
    species: json["species"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "birthdate": birthdate,
    "sex": sexValues.reverse[sex],
    "age": age?.toJson(),
    "height": height?.toJson(),
    "weight": weight?.toJson(),
    "bloodType": bloodTypeValues.reverse[bloodType],
    "kekkeiGenkai": kekkeiGenkai,
    "classification": classification,
    "tailedBeast": tailedBeast,
    "occupation": occupation,
    "affiliation": List<dynamic>.from(affiliation.map((x) => x)),
    "team": team,
    "clan": clan,
    "titles": titles == null ? [] : List<dynamic>.from(titles!.map((x) => x)),
    "status": status,
    "kekkeiMōra": kekkeiMra,
    "partner": partner,
    "species": species,
  };
}

class Age {
  String? partI;
  String? partIi;
  String? academyGraduate;
  String? chuninPromotion;
  String? blankPeriod;
  String? borutoMovie;
  String? borutoManga;

  Age({
    this.partI,
    this.partIi,
    this.academyGraduate,
    this.chuninPromotion,
    this.blankPeriod,
    this.borutoMovie,
    this.borutoManga,
  });

  factory Age.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Age(
    partI: json["Part I"],
    partIi: json["Part II"],
    academyGraduate: json["Academy Graduate"],
    chuninPromotion: json["Chunin Promotion"],
    blankPeriod: json["Blank Period"],
    borutoMovie: json["Boruto Movie"],
    borutoManga: json["Boruto Manga"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Part I": partI,
    "Part II": partIi,
    "Academy Graduate": academyGraduate,
    "Chunin Promotion": chuninPromotion,
    "Blank Period": blankPeriod,
    "Boruto Movie": borutoMovie,
    "Boruto Manga": borutoManga,
  };
}

enum BloodType {
  A,
  AB,
  B,
  O
}

final bloodTypeValues = EnumValues({
  "A": BloodType.A,
  "AB": BloodType.AB,
  "B": BloodType.B,
  "O": BloodType.O
});

class Height {
  String? partI;
  String? partIi;
  String? blankPeriod;
  String? gaiden;
  String? borutoMovie;
  String? borutoManga;

  Height({
    this.partI,
    this.partIi,
    this.blankPeriod,
    this.gaiden,
    this.borutoMovie,
    this.borutoManga,
  });

  factory Height.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Height(
    partI: json["Part I"],
    partIi: json["Part II"],
    blankPeriod: json["Blank Period"],
    gaiden: json["Gaiden"],
    borutoMovie: json["Boruto Movie"],
    borutoManga: json["Boruto Manga"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Part I": partI,
    "Part II": partIi,
    "Blank Period": blankPeriod,
    "Gaiden": gaiden,
    "Boruto Movie": borutoMovie,
    "Boruto Manga": borutoManga,
  };
}

enum Sex {
  FEMALE,
  FILE_GENDER_VARIOUS_SVG_VARIOUS,
  MALE
}

final sexValues = EnumValues({
  "Female": Sex.FEMALE,
  "File:Gender Various.svg Various": Sex.FILE_GENDER_VARIOUS_SVG_VARIOUS,
  "Male": Sex.MALE
});

class Weight {
  String? partI;
  String? partIi;

  Weight({
    this.partI,
    this.partIi,
  });

  factory Weight.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Weight(
    partI: json["Part I"],
    partIi: json["Part II"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Part I": partI,
    "Part II": partIi,
  };
}

class Rank {
  NinjaRank ninjaRank;
  String? ninjaRegistration;

  Rank({
    required this.ninjaRank,
    this.ninjaRegistration,
  });

  factory Rank.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Rank(
    ninjaRank: NinjaRank.fromJson(json["ninjaRank"]),
    ninjaRegistration: json["ninjaRegistration"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "ninjaRank": ninjaRank.toJson(),
    "ninjaRegistration": ninjaRegistration,
  };
}

class NinjaRank {
  String? partI;
  String? gaiden;
  String? blankPeriod;
  String? partIi;

  NinjaRank({
    this.partI,
    this.gaiden,
    this.blankPeriod,
    this.partIi,
  });

  factory NinjaRank.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => NinjaRank(
    partI: json["Part I"],
    gaiden: json["Gaiden"],
    blankPeriod: json["Blank Period"],
    partIi: json["Part II"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Part I": partI,
    "Gaiden": gaiden,
    "Blank Period": blankPeriod,
    "Part II": partIi,
  };
}

class VoiceActors {
  dynamic japanese;
  dynamic english;

  VoiceActors({
    required this.japanese,
    required this.english,
  });

  factory VoiceActors.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VoiceActors(
    japanese: json["japanese"],
    english: json["english"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "japanese": japanese,
    "english": english,
  };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
    return reverseMap;
  }
}

At the very least is I hope to get a solution for my specific problem. In the best case scenario I'm hoping to learn about how the error developed and changes I should be making, why the method I used isn't preferred and if there is an universal way to do it for both maps and list.
I am a beginner currently learning coding and have read different places but no one is explaining it. Different solutions aren't working and people aren't explaining their methods

check your characterList list have this property's json["characters"], json["currentPage"], json["pageSize"], json["total"]

A lot of confusion would be resolved simply by renaming the instance variable
characters to something like:
class Character {
  List<CharacterElement> characterElements;
  ...

and by naming lists of CharacterElements accordingly.
In the line that results in an error:
data = characterList.map((json) => Character.fromJson(json)).toList();

characterList represents a list of CharacterElements, yet you call the factory constructor of the class Character. The error occurs in the line:
characters: List<CharacterElement>.from(json["characters"].map(...

since there is no key "characters".

I would recommend validating your json map in the .fromJson factory constructors before proceeding to construct the object. See:Validating incoming json

You should modify the data variable to this:
data = characterList.map((json) => CharacterElement.fromJson(json)).toList();


This brings up a similar error as I had shown in the above solution. And it is not possible to only change one line, changing means you have to change everything to target the CharacterElement.

If you are getting null value error it means that one of the elements you declared as required has been absent or has a null value in json. Try to check if that is the case

Well Seems like you are returning list of Character object.
Try returning Character element.
Model you created is absolutely correct you just need to learn how to use it.
 List<CharacterElement> data = [];

    final uri = Uri.parse(baseUri+characters);
    try{
      final response = await http.get(
          uri,
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: access_token,
          }
      );
      print('uri: $uri');
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);

      if(response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299){
        final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        print('jsonResponse: $jsonResponse');
        Character? characterData = characterFromJson(response.body);

        print('characterData: $characterData');
        print('just checking data');

        // Map json list to character list
        data = characterData?.characters ?? [];

        print('data: $data');
      }
    }catch(e){
      print('error: $e');
      return data;
    }
    print('Here\'s the data: $data');
    return data;
  }


I had tried this the two solutions above, I get this error.                                                                     error: Null check operator used on a null value
